# How to return the user object with exercise fields added?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am doing this exercise tracker REST api project on FreeCodeCamp. My code seems to give the correct output but it is failing to pass the test **can add an exercise to any user by posting form data userId(_id), description, duration, and optionally date to /api/exercise/add. If no date supplied it will use current date. App will return the user object with the exercise fields added**.
My code for this particular test

```
app.post("/api/exercise/add", urlencodedParser, async (req, res) => {
  const params = req.body;

  try {
    if (
      params.description === "" ||
      params.duration === "" ||
      params.userId === ""
    ) {
      return res.json({ error: "please enter required fields" });
    }

    if (params.date === "" || params.date === null) {
      params.date = new Date().toISOString().substring(0,10);
    }

    var existingUser = await Username.findById({ _id: params.userId });

    if (existingUser._id === null) {
      return res.json({
        error: "could not find the ID. enter the correct one"
      });
    } else if (String(existingUser._id) === params.userId) {
      var assignExercise = Object.create(Exercise);
      assignExercise.description = params.description;
      assignExercise.duration = params.duration;
      assignExercise.date = params.date;

      existingUser.exercise.push({
        description: assignExercise.description,
        duration: assignExercise.duration,
        date: assignExercise.date
      });

      existingUser.count = existingUser.exercise.length;

      await existingUser.save();

      res.json({
        username:existingUser.username,
        id:existingUser._id,
        exercise:existingUser.exercise
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.json({ error: "A problem occured. Solve it" });
  }
});
```

also for the convenience, I wrote the schema like this

```
const Exercise = {
  description: String,
  duration: Number,
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
};

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  count: {
    type: Number
  },
  exercise: {
    type: Array,
    value: Exercise
  }
});

const Username = mongoose.model("Username", userSchema);
```

for this code I get the output

```
{"username":"Tanjim","id":"5f1939c3466036054f22511f","exercise":[{"description":"pushups","duration":"21","date":"2019-09-13"}]}
```

But still can't pass the test. Can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: Have you tried asking in the freecodecamp forum? Those tests are looking for specific conditions. Your code might be correct and still fail to pass the tests. Check [this question](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/apis-and-microservices-projects-exercise-tracker/364236)

Comment: @nibble I asked there too at the same time. Let's see if I get any feedback

Comment: Check the link in my first comment. It is most likely someone has already encountered the same problem.

Comment: @nibble yes checking it. It is sometimes frustrating that you spent hours on writing it, gives the correct output, but for some reason it is not passing the tests

Comment: in my case I was wrong in the way to save the date. I changed it to date and used it in the $gte and $lte filters of the function. And the other error was that I was returning the _id of the new exercise and not the _id of the user in the return object. I solved these problems and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `.toDateString()` to solve this exercise.

```
(new Date()).toDateString()
```

the return will be the expected format: 'Wed Aug 03 2022'.